# python script reading youtube chat stops working for no reason after a while

Tags: python, python-3.x, youtube, chat

basically i have this python script that reads youtube chat using pytchat and saves messages that start with /topic. it usually works for half an hour and eventually closes without giving any errors (i tried running it through cmd and still no errors it just stops). How do i make it work 24/7, do i have any errors in the code?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pytchat

video_id = "iAa3fFY1Hg0"
chat = pytchat.create(video_id)

file_path = "C:/Users/80nin/ai/Assets/chat_log.txt"

def write_to_file(author, message):
    cleaned_message = message[len("/topic"):].strip()
    with open(file_path, "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(f"{author.name} - {cleaned_message}\n")

while True:
    try:
        for c in chat.get().sync_items():
            print(f"{c.author.name} - {c.message}")
            if c.message.startswith("/topic"):
                write_to_file(c.author, c.message)
    except pytchat.ChatDataFinished:
        print("Chat data finished, waiting for new messages...")
        time.sleep(10)  # Adjust the wait time as needed
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}")
        time.sleep(10)  # Wait before trying again to avoid continuous errors
```

i tried running it through cmd and still no errors it just stops

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. How are you running this, is it on your own local machine or deployed somewhere? You say you want to run it 24/7, is the machine you run it on online 24/7? Is the machine set to sleep after a certain period of inactivity?

Comment: @kevin41 thank you! im running this script on my laptop. its not connected to my laptop going to sleep or anything like that. it just stops working out of nowhere.

Comment: @kevin41 maybe the `write_to_file` ends with an unhandled exception. Use try/catch there. Also, consider print in the console the exception details (*or see how to log the exceptions*)...

Answer (score 0):

same problem with code:

```
            while chat.is_alive():
            try:
                for message in chat.get().sync_items():
                    sender = message.author.name
                    text = message.message
                    if text:
                        if use_image:
                            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"<a href='{message.author.channelUrl}'>{sender}</a>, "
                                                            f"<a href='{message.author.imageUrl}'>&#8205;</a>: {text}",
                                                   parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
                        else:
                            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"<a href='{message.author.channelUrl}'>{sender}</a>: "
                                                            f"{text}", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred while processing chat: {e}")
                # handle the error here, for example, by sending an error message to the user
            if not is_running:
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("chat is not alive!")
        return
```

it works 60 mins and after i'll have "chat is not alive". no matter when i'll start fetching 10:00 or 14:37 or 21:49 it will be working only 60 mins. this problem is for 2 months long, before it may works hours and stops with another reason, not with while chat.is_alive(). Also if i'll start code at 10:00 and manually canceling at 10:55, then restart it - code will stop at 11:00 anyway. after i have another 60 mins for fetching after restart. pc is desktop and rpi 3b have same result.
But i found cheap solution, here is my code:

```
async def relay_chat(video_id: str, chat_id: str):
global is_running
while is_running:
    try:
        chat = pytchat.create(video_id=video_id)
        while chat.is_alive():
            try:
                for message in chat.get().sync_items():
                    sender = message.author.name
                    text = message.message
                    if text:
                        if use_image:
                            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"<a href='{message.author.channelUrl}'>{sender}</a>, "
                                                            f"<a href='{message.author.imageUrl}'>&#8205;</a>: {text}",
                                                   parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
                        else:
                            await bot.send_message(chat_id, f"<a href='{message.author.channelUrl}'>{sender}</a>: "
                                                            f"{text}", parse_mode=ParseMode.HTML)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error occurred while processing chat: {e}")
                # handle the error here, for example, by sending an error message to the user
            if not is_running:
                break
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("chat is not alive!")
        # return               <---- removed here
    except aiohttp.ClientConnectorError as e:
        print(f"No internet connection: {e}")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)  # waiting for 10 sec
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        print("Timeout error: check your internet connection")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)  # waiting for 10 sec
    await asyncio.sleep(2)    # <---- added here
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35643865)

Comment: ok sorry already edited